# Change logo on language change Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to make the main logo of the store change when I change language.
My company has a different name in english (originally in French).

Here's the code I have :

I have changed (in catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/common/header.tpl)

```
 <?php if ($logo) { ?>
  <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

For :

```
<?php
if($lang == 'fr'){
$logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_FR_PNG.png';
} elseif($lang == 'en'){
$logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_EN_PNG.png';
}
?> 
<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

But it's not working, the logo does not change, but I don't understand what's wrong in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: is `$lang` being set? What is actually being output - is it always outputting the English version, or the French one? What if `$lang` is neither 'en' or 'fr'?

Comment: Well the $lang is set when you're on the website. By default, it loads the site in french, so $lang = fr if the website is in french. Sorry I'm not very used to Opencart.

Comment: I'd try adding some debugging to the start of your code to make sure that `$lang` is what you're expecting it to be - I can't see anything wrong with the code, so I can only think that `$lang` isn't being set properly.

Comment: What code should I use to make sure that $lang is set?

Comment: I'd start with an `echo '**' . $lang;` and see what it printed out.

Comment: It works correctly. It prints "FR" when the site is in french, and "EN" when it's in english. What's wrong then?

Comment: You're checking `$lang == 'en'`, but it's actually `EN` - try changing the if statement to look for it in upper case to see if it makes a difference. Also, are you setting a default value for `$logo` anywhere?

Comment: Check out if your logo's being cached, reload page with **ctrl+F5**

Comment: andrewsi - I typed EN but it appears as "en".
fitheflow - I did try refreshing the page, but it's not updating

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that $lang does not contain the language of the currently selected language. This is stored in `$this->config->get('config_language');` in `index.php` just before

```
$language = new Language($languages[$code]['directory']);
```

if you are curious to see how. You can simply amend your code to the following which should work

```
<?php
$lang = $this->config->get('config_language'); // ADDED LINE
if($lang == 'fr'){
    $logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_FR_PNG.png';
} elseif($lang == 'en'){
    $logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_EN_PNG.png';
}
?> 
<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Alternatively assuming your original logo set was

```
image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_FR_PNG.png
```

You could just use

```
<?php
$logo = str_replace('_FR_', '_' . strtoupper($this->config->get('config_language')) . '_', $logo);
?> 
<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Which will allow you to use the two letter prefix automatically for each new language logo

*Note that none of the code above has been tested but should work in theory*

Comment: Thanks for your input. Everything sounded very logic, but it's not working. The logo stays the same...I really don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Go into the admin of OpenCart to the languages section and edit a language. Look in the URL for something like language_id=1. Make a note of the language ID for each language.

In your code, put the following:

```
<?php

// $this->config->get('config_language_id') returns the language ID currently active for the session

switch ($this->config->get('config_language_id')) {

 case 1 : // Replace the "1" with your English language ID
   // The English logo
   $logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_EN_PNG.png';
   break;

 case 2 : // Replace the "2" with your French language ID
   // The French logo
   $logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_FR_PNG.png';
   break;

 default :
    // The default logo if none of the above cases match
   $logo = 'image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_EN_PNG.png';

}
?>

<?php if ($logo) { ?>
<div id="logo">
   <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
   </a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

As a note, this logic should really be in a controller rather than in a template view file. OpenCart doesn't let you extend core controllers so don't worry too much about putting it in the view, but if you want to do it properly have a look at something like vQmod to insert it into the controller.

(Slightly off topic; there's a vQmod-ish-type-thing built in to an upcoming version of OpenCart which should hopefully let you edit the controllers without being dirty and downloading vQmod - but I couldn't say how long it'll be till that's released).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said, but it's not working :S...nothing appears at the place where the logo is supposed to be.

Comment: View the page source. Is there a valid URL in the image src attribute? If there is, click it and make sure that you don't get a 404. If you get a 404

Comment: No 404. I see the valid URL to the image src. I have a logo uploaded via the admin panel "Settings" page. I tried deleting it and letting the head.tpl file do the job. But when I do that, no logo appears at all.

Comment: Do you have a link you could show me what you mean? If there is an img and it has a valid src, then there's no reason it shouldn't appear. The only other possible reasons would be your browser cache somehow thinking the image doesn't exist, or you have some CSS rules which hide the image.

Comment: What I mean is that yes, there is a valid src. But that image is probably linked with the image I uploaded in the Settings page of the admin panel. But since I added a PHP function in the header file, I guessed that by deleting the logo uploaded in the "Settings" page of the admin panel would not change anything, since the link on the good logo for each language is done in a PHP function. Sorry, it's hard to explain...

Comment: When you say "deleting the logo uploaded in the "Settings" page" - do you mean you actually opened the image manager and deleted the image, or did you just not assign it as the store logo? You don't need to have it assigned as the store logo for the way you're doing it in the header, but the image must still exist in the directory

Comment: Worth pointing out that the new vQmod-ish type thing won't have the functionality of vQmod itself and all vQmod's will need to be rewritten to work with it successfully

Comment: Thanks for your input Jay Gilford

Comment: @AdamNicholson `OpenCart doesn't let you extend core controllers` - You sure? Because I am pretty sure if something is an *opensource* that I am allowed to edit anything. That means I am able to edit core controllers, too.

Comment: @shadyyx - That's probably vQmod you're thinking about which I referenced in my answer. It lets you search files for a pattern and then add/modify/remove chunks of code. While this works, I would rather see an OpenCart which was a bit more hmvc and allowed you to actually `extend` a class.

Comment: @AdamNicholson I know what `vQmod` is and I am using it for all the extensions I am developing. Anyway, You are still able to edit any piece of the source code of the core system - it is opensource. OpenCart is not even a true MVC. HMVC still would not bring an option to extend the classes - it is modularity that brings an option. And OpenCart is nor modular.

Comment: @shadyyx - I may have misread your initial comment. Yes you can edit whatever you want, but if you edit core classes then you immediately loose the ability to upgrade easily. What I was getting at is that if you want to edit code then you're forced to either put it in a view file (where most of the time it shouldn't really be) or pick up an extension such as vQmod. Personally I don't like the idea of having to go get extensions before I can modify an open source platform without risking upgradability.

Comment: @AdamNicholson And what is so bad about vQmod extension? Actually it is the cleanest solution - it incorporates the source code preserving the original upgradability and bringing You the desired functionality... So what is so bad about it? Explain some reasons, please...

Comment: @shadyyx I'm making this my last comment because you're clearly out looking for an argument or something. See my last comment `Personally I don't like the idea of having to go get extensions before I can modify an open source platform without risking upgradability.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that should work:

Open up Your controller `catalog\controller\common\header.php` and find this line of code:

```
$this->data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

(should be line 30 if OC version 1.5.5.1) and comment this line out (add `//` before the line).

Now right under this commented line (should stay within the `if` statement) add this:

```
$this->load->model('localisation/language');
$language = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguage($this->config->get('config_language_id'));
$logo = $server . 'image/' . $language['code'] . '/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
$this->data['logo'] = file_exists($logo) ? $logo : $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

By this code You set up a path to Your logo image like this

- `.../image/EN/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc.png`
- `.../image/FR/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc.png`

Make sure that in Your admin You set the logo like You normally should (so it should be stored in `image/data/`) folder and then manualy copy the english/french copy to the folder `image/EN/data` or `image/FR/data` - **note that the image name must be the same**. The code should test whether the file exists in that directory and pick up the default one if it does not.

The code in Your header template file should remain the same.

Comment: The "image/EN" and "FR" folder do not exist, is that normal? I created it, and did what you told me. And now the logo I normally set in the admin panel do not appear anymore. The image link seems to be broken on the front-end. But I checked on my server in "image/data" and the logo file is there. But I checked the link, and the image is now linking to "image/image/data/..." instead of "image/data". What's wrong?

Comment: Sometimes just dummy copy-pasting is not enough. Try to solve the path to image problem, I think the whole solution is good and should work. What value is in `$this->config->get('config_logo');`? Of course `/EN/` and `/FR/` folders didn't exist and You had to create them...

Comment: The path of the image is not even linking to "image/EN/data" (or FR). And since I do not see this path in the code you posted, I'm not sure how to fix this then. Thank you

Comment: Try echoing the `$logo` variable after the line `$logo = $server . 'image/' . $language['code'] . '/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');` - what does it contain? Usually `$this->config->get('config_logo')` conatins something like `data/My_Logo.png` - that's why we add `/image/` and 'EN/' before the path...The `EN` part should come from `$language['code']` part...

Comment: It echoes "MyWebsite.com/image/image/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc_FR_PNG.png". Why it's not having the "EN/data/Lg_Axesoirs_Blanc.png" path?